# The image in the array isnt being detected?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

- I am new to coding so sorry for any generic mistakes
- This code is meant to go from red then go through the array and back to red. however after i have set the array position back to 0 the image is blank, and then skips out red on all other attempts.
- the image starts of as the red traffic light.

  ```
  var position = 0
  var TrafficL = ["Traffic_light_amber_red.png","Traffic_light_green.png","Traffic_light_amber.png","Traffic_light_red.png"];

  function ChangeImage() {
      if(position < TrafficL.length - 1) {
      document.getElementById("myImage").src = TrafficL[position];
      position++
      }
  }
  function RestartPos() {
      if (position==4)
      document.getElementById("myImage").src = position["Traffic_light_red.png"]
      position=0
  }
  ```

Comment: what is supposed to be returned by `position["Traffic_light_red.png"]` ?

Comment: Is every teacher now giving traffic lights for homework? Seems like this is now the daily question.

Comment: Oh, am i meant to have the name of the array here?

Comment: How are you calling the functions?

Comment: +Andy im using two buttons with onclick, one for ChangeImage and the other for RestartPos

Answer (score 1):

Multiple issues in your RestartPos()

1) if condition should have both the condition

2) `position["Traffic_light_red.png"]` doesn't make sense (it will given an error since position is not an array or object, it is an integer) it should be `TrafficL[position]`

```
function RestartPos() 
{
    if (position==4)
    {
      position=0;
      document.getElementById("myImage").src = TrafficL[position];
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `position = 0` be before the image source change ? And the `if` is pretty useless then.